# How to detect • symbols and transform them into HTML ul's using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I have some copy that I would like to transform into HTML using JQuery.

The following is a sample of the text I am working with in a textarea:

```
    Monday 28th October 2013

    18:30 Some text 

    17:30 Another bit of text 

    Day two Tuesday 29th October 2013

    11:00 Some title goes here

    • Point 1

    • Point 2

    • Point 3

    Some text to go here

    18:30 Some text
```

I am trying to transform the lists which have been made using • symbols into proper html lists wrapped in ul tags whilst removing the symbols. I would also like to make any times bolded.

This would be the intended result:

```html
<b>11:00</b> Some title goes here

<ul>
<li>Point 1</li>
<li>Point 2</li>
<li>Point 3</li>
</ul>
```

I have very little understanding of regex, and can't find any resources on this specific issue so any pointers would be greatly apreciated!

I have tried using the following code to make the times bold, but I couldn't get it to work for some reason:

```
var oldHtml = $('textarea').html();
var newHtml = oldHtml.replace(^\d{2}:\d{2}$)/g,"<b>$1</b>");
$('textarea').html(newHtml);​
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post the code you have attempted to write yourself, as per the 'Good Question' guidelines in the FAQ.

Comment: Can you use CSS to rid yourself of the • symbols or does it strictly have to be a regex?

Comment: Rory - I have attached the regex I tried for the times, it didn't work though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider you have the following HTML textarea and div to display html

```
<div id="display">Entered html will show here</div>
<textarea id="markup"></textarea>
```

First you need to split lines

```
var lines = $('#markup').val().split(/\n/);
var html = '';
```

Then loop through your lines and check which starts with a •

```
for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
   if(lines[i].match(/^(•|\t)/)) {
      html += '<li>'+lines[i].replace('•', '').replace('\t','')+'</li>';
   } else {
      html += lines[i];
   }
}
```

Now you can do the following to show the new formatted html in some div

```
$('#display').html(html);
```

Comment: Principal is basically sound but, (1) you did not account for whitespace (tabs) before the bullet point character, and (2) you did not remove the bullet point character and so you get it twice in the resulting HTML. (and using `+=` is not a best practice). With a bit more work this could be a really sweet solution, say for transforming content from Office documents into HTML. See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5Qy5t/

Comment: @nothingisnecessary Its true, it can be improved, trying to give the Idea to OP so he can explore it and improve it to his needs

Comment: I understood the question when I saw your answer. +1 Adding some `<li>` CSS to that would be perfect. That is, if that's a possibility for OP.

Comment: Thanks for fixing to remove the extra bullet point. And +1 for the technique of breaking into lines and using regex, you beat me to the punch

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to be getting there, now I just need to wrap the <li> in a <ul>, I should be able to do this part myself. Thanks again this really helped!

Comment: $( "li.third-item" ).siblings().wrapAll('<ul />') is what I am using to wrap them.